# Chrome: Email Page Location Does nothing?

Tags: google-chrome

Ok, this should be so simple. On the Chrome menu bar it has a link:

Email page location

It does nothing. How to a get that one to work?

thanks

Comment: This seems like it might be a better question for a different SE site...

Comment: are you sure this isn't an addon? It's not on my Chrome and I don't recognise it as a standard thing

Comment: Woah, u may be right, i'm coming from a Firefox world. Ok, I found an extension that works. Will default to that. Just seemed super easy to do in FF, now I need an extra click.



> Send from Gmail (by Google) 1.16
Makes Gmail your default email application and provides a button to compose a Gmail message to quickly share a link via email